# ArviZ plot_trace does not properly plot multidimensional variables

Tags: python, pymc3, arviz

I'm attempting to run a basic test model using PyMC3, but I've found the ArviZ `plot_trace` function won't properly show my traces.

#### Code

```
from scipy import stats
import arviz as az
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from theano import shared
from sklearn import preprocessing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with basic_model:

        # Priors for unknown model parameters
        alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sigma=10)
        beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sigma=10, shape=2)
        sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sigma=1)

        # Expected value of outcome
        mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2

        # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
        Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=Y)

        # draw 500 posterior samples
        trace = pm.sample(5000)

    az.plot_trace(trace, compact = False)
```

The `beta` parameter is multidimensional, and has both `beta[0]` and `beta[1]`, but the ArviZ trace only shows `beta[0]`:

#### Trace Plot

[image]

If I run the trace plot as `az.plot_trace(trace, compact = True)`, then I do see both dimensions of `beta` properly overlaid. I only observed this issue when trying to plot the dimensions in separate axes with `compact = False`.

---

#### Versions

- ArviZ: 0.6.1
- Numpy: 1.18.1
- SciPy: 1.4.1
- xarray: 0.15.0
- Matplotlib: 3.1.3

Comment: which ArviZ version are you using?

Comment: ArviZ: 0.6.1, Numpy: 1.18.1, SciPy: 1.4.1, xarray: 0.15.0, Matplotlib: 3.1.3

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running into [this bug](https://github.com/arviz-devs/arviz/issues/1023). I'd recommend updating ArviZ to its latest version (0.7.0 at the time of writing) which already includes a fix for this particular bug.

If you had some kind of version constraint, then [disabling numba](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/notebooks/Numba.html) should fix the issue.